# Facebook API pending requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know this have been asked several times, and I have already read several posts in here, but somehow it doesn't work for me. Even when I gave myself ALL permissions and not only 'read_requests'.

I have been trying with FQL

```php
try {
  $me = $facebook->api('/me');

  $currentPage=1;
  $currentPost=1;
  $currentDate="";

  $list="";
  $arrDate=array();

  $fql    =   "SELECT uid_from FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to = me()";
  $param  =   array(
   'method'    => 'fql.query',
   'query'     => $fql,
   'callback'  => ''
  );
  $fqlResult     =   $facebook->api($param);

  var_dump($fqlResult);

  foreach($fqlResult as $row){
    var_dump($row);
  }

}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  echo 'error: <pre>';
  var_dump($e);
}
```

And also in the Graph Explorer with the following line

```
MY_ID?fields=friendrequests.fields(created_time),name
```

But Graph Explorer says I don't have permission, even when I gave myself full permission. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: **The Graph API Explorer is a totally different application.** Permissions that you granted to *your* application are not the same permissions that you granted the Graph API Explorer application.

Comment: But neither Explorer or my application, it doesn't work.

Comment: Contact with Facebook support. I've checked this in GraphAPI exploere and it works for me. I have active, approved, public invisible account.

Comment: I'm not sure where I can contact their support? And are you sure it's not just me mistaken something? I go to this site [link]( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) give permission to read_requests and for instance FQL: `SELECT uid_from FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to = me()` and it will return me `{"data": []}`

Comment: i've tried with `?fields=friendrequests.fields(created_time),name`

Comment: I see a problem, that this does only show requests sent to you. I want to find both incomng and outgoing, and not just incoming.